# How to insert text field's data into the database using FMDB method

Tags: xcode4, fmdb

I have a database with 5 columns.. I should update the database with the values typed in the textfields..

```
-(void)insertData:(int)insGI:(NSString*)insVis:(NSString*)insp4p:(NSString*)insCM:(NSString*)insSC:(NSString*)insCEL
{

[db beginTransaction];

NSString *stringSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE CreateGoal SET Column1 = %@, Column2 = %@, Column3 = %@, Column4 = %@, Column5 = %@ WHERE rowid = %d ", insVis, insp4p, insCM, insSC, insCEL, insGI];
[db executeQuery:stringSQL];
[db commit];
```

}

update a table with new values..

```
-(IBAction)someaction:(id)sender

{

 sc = text1.text;

NSLog(@"\n \n \n SC = %@",sc);
printf("\n \n \n HHHHHHHHHHH");
p4p = text2.text;
vis = text3.text;
cm = text4.text;
cel = text5.text;
 [[DBManager getInstance]insertData:gid:vis:p4p:cm:sc:cel]; 

}
```

calling like this.. Problem is the values are not getting stored in the database.. where have i gone wrong?? Please help..

THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use executeUpdate for writing on fmdb. Also, I strongly advise you to avoid stringWithFormat and use the parsing capabilities of fmdb, which can perform type checking at runtime.

```
[db executeUpdate:@"UPDATE CreateGoal SET Column1 = ?, Column2 = ?", value1, value2, nil]; //check as always the nil at the end
```

hope it helps!

Comment: thanks a lot.. this surely helped.. but y exactly is string with format not recommended?

Comment: because if you should change your mind in the future and change the type for a variable (from int to NSNumber or similar) you should find and replace all your code. I know because I did :)